# Lightbox not showing all the caption

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, lightbox, lightbox2

Only one data comes from the data caption attribute.
Can you tell me how to display three different titles on the lightbox?
The lightbox opens up when we click the cube.
Providing my fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZrpLT/74/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span10">
    <div class="melonhtml5_gallery">
      <div data-caption="<div>Paul Scholes</div> <div>Wayne Rooney</div> <div>Sir Alex Ferguson</div>" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/thumbnails/inventory.png"></div>
      <div data-caption="<p>car</p> <p>bus</p> <p>bike</p>" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/thumbnails/yourFile.png">
    </div>                            
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.caption` is set to a fixed 30px height in code.

I have overriden it using css: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrpLT/85/

It is set on line 297 in the javascript code if you want to change it there instead.

Comment: thanks for your reply but in case of blue cube i see only car and bus but i dont see bike whats the reason....

Comment: You are using <p> elements instead of <div> elements for second one. They have different heights (p has margin bottom by default).

Comment: is it possible to give a tags and make it as link

Comment: Don't think there is any limitation on what you can put it

Comment: for the output did u make changes only on html and css or even the js

Comment: @sunno: its not working if i give sth like this <div data-caption="&lt;a href="http://www.w3schools.com/" &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt;View/Edit&lt;/div&gt; &lt;div&gt;Labels&lt;/div&gt;" data-image="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/thumbnails/inventory.png"></div>

Comment: I did html encode the text in data-caption as I thought this was the issue at first. It is not needed. Please create a new question describing the problem ("it is not working" is not helpful). New jsfiddle link helps as well.